# Extension to increase the maximum registers to compile a shader program?

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I am trying to store a kernel in GLSL code as an immediate array of vec4 as follow:

```
vec4 kernel1[512] = vec4[512](
   vec4(0,0,0,0), ...);
vec4 kernel2[512] = vec4[512](
   vec4(0,0,0,0), ...);
vec4 identity matrix[4] = vec4[4](...);
```

All of them are used in the GLSL code. The problem is now, the vulkan cannot use the shader and debug extension reports the following error message:

> Constant register limit exceeded at XXXXX; more than 1024 registers needed to compiled program

I have the same setup in my dx11 code and everything works fine. I was wondering if there is an extension which allows me to use more 1024 registers. I would be appreciated if you know another solution to have the same setup in vulkan.

Comment: Sounds like a driver message. Do you get that message with validation layers disabled (but with debug extension enabled)?

Comment: @KrOoze no, both are enabled. As I understood, to have debug extension working, the validation layers needs to be enabled too.

Comment: Usually they can be used independently (you can query if that is the case with `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, ..., ...)` and besides you would get `VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT` on instance creation). I just want to verify that the message comes from the driver and not from the validation layers. At which point I will tell you that TMK Vulkan does not impose such limit (and it is all about this specific driver implementation), and so no extension can help. Then I will recommend using Uniform Buffers instead.

Comment: Why should nvidia implement vk driver more limited than dx11? Does that make sense?
Isn't the immediate array faster than uniform buffers?

Comment: Considering there are OpenGL related issues with exactly the same message I would assume it is some kind of driver codebase inheritance. Another worldview can be that DX11 does something behind your back to make it work, for which you pay an unknown cost. While Vulkan driver version tries to adhere to the paradigm of explicitness and tries to inform instead that you strayed of the fast path. Either way that's a question for NV. ;; I wouldn't try to guess which is faster. But uniform buffers are intended for "medium sized arrays of constants" and you seem to have these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SPIR-V generated for this shader is a pretty straightforward translation of your code. The driver's compiler will need to store at least 1024 vec4 literal values somewhere to create the dynamic arrays. Think of this as data stored in the code segment. Apparently this exceeds some internal limit Nvidia has (which probably isn't valid, but you don't want to do this anyway, see below).

I don't have a DX11 fxc handy, but if I remember right it would take code like this and move the kernel1 and kernel2 declarations into, essentially, a hidden constant buffer reserved for the hlsl compiler. This was done by the front-end compiler, not the driver's compiler (though the driver could map that reserved constant buffer to code-segment data, or to a normal constant buffer slot, or something else, whatever it wanted).

Vulkan and SPIR-V don't have a uniform (constant) buffer binding reserved for the compiler, but you want effectively the same thing the HLSL compiler is doing. Just replace those declarations with uniform buffer declarations, and put the data in those buffers via the API.